# parse.com httpresponse return json not text

Tags: json, xcode, swift, parse-platform

For some strange reason i cant seem to loop through the result returned by my cloudcode function.I think its because it's returning a text in json format not actual json? How can i parse the httpResponse value into a json to be used later?
I've tried using

```
response.success(JSON.parse(httpResponse.text)); // and httpResponse.data
```

**Parse.com CloudCode**

```
 Parse.Cloud.define("test", function(request, response) {
        return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=the+eagles&type=artist&limit=1'

        }).then(function(httpResponse) {
            response.success(httpResponse.text);


        }, 
        function (error) {
            response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        });
    });
```

Swift Code

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("test", withParameters: ["" : ""]) { (result: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) in
        let json = JSON(result!); //SwiftyJSON
        print(json["artist"]) //returns null
        //print(json[0])//returns null
        //print(json) 
}
```

Sample JSON

```
{
artists: {
href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=the+eagles&offset=0&limit=1&type=artist",
items: [
{
genres: [
"country rock",
"mellow gold",
"soft rock"
],
href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0ECwFtbIWEVNwjlrfc6xoL",
id: "0ECwFtbIWEVNwjlrfc6xoL",
images: [
{
height: 668,
url: "https://i.scdn.co/image/173519085c3eb8301fbeb744b0b92b6747938ab3",
width: 1000
}
]

}
}
```

Comment: The sample json you've posted is not valid json. You are missing `""` around all the keys, such as `artists` -> `"artists"`, etc.. You are also missing a `]` and `}` before the last `}` in the file.

Comment: You can use this website to verify if it is valid json or not: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: Json sample was edited to save some space

Answer (score 1):

You need to return httpResponse.data instead of httpResponse.text, given that the content-type in your response object is application/json

Comment: console returns an uncaught syntax error, when i do that. JSON.parse(httpResponse.text) allows me to view the json data as a whole but i cant access fields within

Comment: when trying to parse the json received with SwiftyJSON. let json = JSON(result!);

Comment: Well httpResponse.data is already been parsed for you. Try to access the result object without attempting to parse it with Swifty

Comment: Using httpResponse.data instead of httpResponse.text did it for me. You can then cast the response object as an NSDictionary and you're good.